# ExecuteReader: CommandText property not initialized

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

```
public DataTable Liste()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-JHLF03K\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=OtelWebSite;Integrated Security=True");
    string sql = "";
    SqlDataAdapter dap = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);  
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    con.Open();
    dap.Fill(table);

    sql += "SELECT ";
    sql += "O.Id, ";
    sql += "O.OdaTurId,";
    sql += "T.Ad AS OdaTur, ";
    sql += "O.Ad, ";
    sql += "O.KatNo, ";
    sql += "O.Aciklama, ";
    sql += "K.Tanim AS Durum ";
    sql += "FROM Oda O, Kod K,OdaTur T  ";
    sql += "WHERE O.Durum = K.Kod ";
    sql += "AND T.Id = O.OdaTurId ";
    sql += "ORDER BY O.Id,O.OdaTurId";



    con.Close();
    return table;
}
```

I get an error

> ExecuteReader: CommandText property not initialized

on this line of code:

```
dap.Fill(table);
```

Comment: Did you initialize the CommandText property?

Comment: Write your sql before you use it. Right now, your sql string is empty when you use it. Favor a StringBuilder over concatenation if you are going to write them like that.  Also put your disposable objects into using {} blocks so they automatically get disposed.

Comment: Think logically about your code. If you try to fill the table using the query within `sql` before you actually add the query to `sql`, what did you think was going to happen?

Comment: Side note, SqlConnection implements IDisposable, so you should make use of the `using` keyword to ensure it's cleaned up when you're done with it. Database connections are typically limited resources.

Comment: Also, the SqlDataAdapter is IDisposable, so should also be in a `using` block.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot execute and empty sql query.
Move your sql query creation to the top before the line that creates the DataAdapter

```
public DataTable Liste()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-JHLF03K\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=OtelWebSite;Integrated Security=True");
    string sql = "";

    sql += "SELECT ";
    sql += "O.Id, ";
    sql += "O.OdaTurId,";
    sql += "T.Ad AS OdaTur, ";
    sql += "O.Ad, ";
    sql += "O.KatNo, ";
    sql += "O.Aciklama, ";
    sql += "K.Tanim AS Durum ";
    sql += "FROM Oda O, Kod K,OdaTur T  ";
    sql += "WHERE O.Durum = K.Kod ";
    sql += "AND T.Id = O.OdaTurId ";
    sql += "ORDER BY O.Id,O.OdaTurId";

    SqlDataAdapter dap = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);  
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    con.Open();
    dap.Fill(table);

    con.Close();
    return table;
}
```

Comment: And, don't forget, both your connection object and your data adapter object are `IDisposable`.  You should wrap the code that uses them in `using` statements.  As others have mentioned, concatenating strings the way you do is not the right way to do it.  If you want to have everything on a separate line, consider using `@"Select...[text with new lines]"` or `var sql = "Select" + [newline] "O.Id, " + ...`